# How to make Dllimport correctly in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c++, visual-studio-2010, dllimport

ive had some problems building a correct .dll from a c++-project to my c#-project.
I played around with the c++-project-properties and got a .dll file which i can add and refer to in my c# web-project. I use Dllimport to make a function call to the .dll like this:

```
[DllImport("Filename.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void Function1([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string src, 
                             int srcLen, 
                             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder dst,
                             int dstLen)
```

The c++ function header is:

```
__declspec(dllimport) void Function1(unsigned char *src, 
                     unsigned long srclen, 
                     unsigned char *dst, 
                     unsigned long dstlen);
```

Im calling Function1 in c# with this:

```
string strSrc = "Something";
StringBuilder strDest = new StringBuilder(kryptlen-1);
int l = strSrc.Length();
Function1(strSrc, l, strDest, l);
```

No exceptions or errors are occuring, though im not getting the output im expecting. The function is a decrypting method that takes an encrypted string(src) and returns the decrypted version of this (dst).

Is it the way ive generated the .dll file or is it the wrong way im calling the function? Im running out of ideas ive tried most combinations.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: You can turn on unmanaged debugging in your C# project settings and step from you C# code into your C++ code. Hopefully that will provide you with some insight into your problem.

Comment: @Martin: Can I do this anywhere for web-applications? Can't find it.

Comment: Actually I think you can. At the bottom of the **Web** tab there is a **Debuggers** section with a **Native Code** option. However, if would avoid doing small tests like that inside a web application. A small console application or a test project is much more suited for testing out snippets of code.

Comment: I enables Native Code, but when i reach my function call to the dll and press F11 it wont jump into the dll.

Comment: Please make sure that your native DLL is a debug build and that the symbols (the PDB file) are available. If you are debugging your web application I would highly recommend doing the tests in a console application to remove ASP.NET from the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time changing the settings back and forth i noticed that the data i had to start with  was the same data i had after a decrypt and an encrypt. So I realized that the encryption/decryption was working. The problem was the data. When i had the correct data i got the correct output!

This is the end setup im stuck with now, hope it can help someone:

```
cryptedString = "CryptedStringFromDataBase";
StringBuilder decryptedString = new StringBuilder(300);
Decrypt(cryptedString, (uint)cryptedString.Length, decryptedString, 300);

[DllImport("Filename.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void Decrypt(string src, UInt32 srcLen, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder dst, UInt32 dstLen);
```

Answer (score 2):

Where'd `UnmanagedType.LPWStr` come from?  There are no wide strings in the C++ declaration.  You're also passing the source length twice, while the variable names suggest you need the source length and the destination buffer capacity.

If `src` is encrypted data as you say, the correct p/invoke signature is probably:

```
[DllImport("Filename.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.CDecl)]
static extern void Function1(byte[] src, 
                             UInt32 srcLen,
                             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder dst,
                             UInt32 dstLen)
```

Trying to force binary data into a Unicode string is a losing proposition.

Comment: UnmanagedType.LPWStr, i was trying out all of the alternatives. Ive tried with LPStr aswell. Tried to change the second length parameter to the buffer size (tried with 200). I get different output but still not correct.

Comment: The thing is that the encrypted data is read from a database table column, with type string. So should i turn this into a byte[]? What type of conversion would that be? Doesn't sounds right.

Comment: @Joakim: Yuck.  The database really should be using a BLOB column.  Anyway, the C++ code will treat it as an array of bytes, so either you can trust p/invoke's default settings, or you can use the `Encoding` class to have some control over the conversion.

Comment: How would u suggest i use the encoding class for my purpose?
Something like this?:

byte[] src = new Byte[encryptString.length];
            System.Text.UTF32Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF32Encoding();
            src = encoding.GetBytes(src);

Comment: @Joakim: `byte[] src = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(src_from_db);`  But maybe you need `Encoding.Unicode`.  Or `Encoding.UTF8`.  Depends on how the binary data was converted to a string when it was being stored into the database.

Comment: `StringBuilder d = new StringBuilder(200);`
`byte[] src = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dbStringEncrypted);`
`Function1(src, l, d, 200);`

`[DllImport("Filename.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`
`static extern void Function1(byte[] src, int srcLen, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder dst, int dstLen);`

I've tried with encoding Unicode and UTF8 aswell nothing will return me anything else than a [] - squaresign, as result. If i remove the calling convention i will get "garbage" of random data again. Any ideas?

Comment: @Joakim: Second argument should be `src.Length`, not `dbStringEncrypted.Count`.

Answer (score 2):

C++ by default unless changed uses a caller( Cdecl ) calling convention.  Your C++ code does not change the calling convention.  Your C# code by default ( unless you change it ) will use a callee convention ( StdCall ).

While this might not be exactly the problem your having it still is technically incorrect.  Even if you were to fix your current problem you likely will end up having a problem because of the calling convention.

> No exceptions or errors are occuring,
>   though im not getting the output im
>   expecting. The function is a
>   decrypting method that takes an
>   encrypted string(src) and returns the
>   decrypted version of this (dst).

What exactly are you getting?

The solution to the calling convention problem is to declare the calling convention.

```
[DllImport("Filename.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)] static extern void Function1([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string src,                               int srcLen,                               [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder dst,                              int dstLen)
```

Comment: If I use CallingConvention.Cdecl i just get "" as output.

As argument src ive got "36ù@oÀKCxrH«=­&~Af1‚3ÊøŒ÷òÈ–üýM)‰¸×Î" which is the encrypted string and as output from the function i get 
Im expecting a string of digits as output. im quite sure the c++ project is working as intended. So must be something else.

Before the callingconvention i had outputs similar to this:

V@-‡_÷r
V@-‡_÷r
V@-‡_÷r
4ÚÆLNþ\;úÂäÈñ;¡XÜ.úWpà£È–üýM)‰¸×Î

Comment: This is a very good point (and one which I've included in my attempt to "fix" the declaration).  +1.  But there's problems with the string handling as well.

Comment: @Ben - I wasn't up to the task of fixing the other problem.  I just noticed the calling convention problem, wasn't up to researching out to send a char* in C# to the library to be honest.

Comment: @Joakim - What you recieved was simply garbage :-)